# how to read the package of redhat linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat

nspluginwrapper-1.4.4-1.el6_3.x86_64

i have question on

1.4.4-1.el6_3

how to read it was it the 1.4.4-1 mean , is it 1.4.4.1 or something else

also on

el6_3 mean el6.3 or not

Comment: why i got minus on my question i try google it but can't find a thing what do you guy expect newbie on linux to find answer on by god telling me ?? .... to be hornest i just didnt know for real what the hell 1.4.4-1 is meanning even my teacher can't answer me that why i ask here just dont understand who give a minus :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nspluginwrapper-1.4.4-1.el6_3.x86_64 can be split as:

- `nspluginwrapper` : short package name
- `1.4.4` : package version as provided by original open source maintainer (not by distro maintainer).
- `1` : package build revision (provided by distro). This mostly differs if distro has applied some patches to make this software work better under this distro. Increases for any new revision.
- `el6_3` : distro id
- `x86_64` : architecture. maybe `i686` (32-bit x86), `x86_64` (64-bit x86), some others and also `noarch` (package is not arch dependent, will work on any arch).

Comment: el6_3 what is _3 or same as  1 on package version

Comment: el6_3 means (Redhat) Enterprise Linux 6, revision 3 (distro revision, not package), also known as RHEL 6.3.

Comment: i have new questions 

if i upgrade patch

For example in my patch have this package like 

nspluginwrapper-1.4.4-3.el6_5.x86_64

from the package above (nspluginwrapper-1.4.4-1.el6_3.x86_64) is it going to effect or not :D

Comment: Since only package revision differs, it should be ok. Typically `sudo yum upgrade` will do everything completely automatically, so you don't really have to think about it

Comment: yep thank you ! i have project on patch checking on linux redhat ... get confuse in manything if i want to check patch what do you think which part i should check first next from package name----- version or el

Comment: In general, packages from one distro like `el6_1` are not guaranteed to be compatible with another like `el6_3`. But if only package revision increased - it is perfectly ok, and most of the time increased package version is also fine - like from `1.4.4` to `1.4.5`

Comment: so if 

i upgrade from  1.4.4-1  to 1.4.4-5   and   1.4.4-1 to 1.4.5-2    should be ok right??
---------------------
also  
-------------------
from  el6_1 to  el6_3  is okay too but maybe have problems right

Comment: yes, that's right. distro change is almost never safe, but small package version or revision is typically no problem